# Triple integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration

Find volume of the region determined by the inequalities

$x>0, y>0,z<8 \text { and } z>x^2+y^2$ using triple integral.

i have taken the limits as follows :

$z$ varies form $x^2+y^2$ to $8$

$x$ varies from $0$ to $\sqrt{8-y^2}$

$y$ varies from $0$ to $2\sqrt 2$

Am i doing it right ?

Comment: I would do it the other way around. Start with $z$ from $0$ to $8$ .. another option would be using Cylindrical Coordinates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system

Comment: is what i have done incorrect ?

Comment: @stg in cylindrical form it will become $$\int_{\theta =0}^{\pi /2}\int_{r=0}^{2\sqrt 2}\int_{z=r^2}^8$$  ??

Comment: Everything you've done looks fine, but what I wanted to point out with my first comment is that for each fixed $z$ you have a quarter circle. In my opionen its just easier to calculate the area of this quarter circle first and THEN to integrate over $z$

Answer (score 1):

stg has you on the right track -- and your method is fine. This kind of thing is a LOT easier in cylindrical, it is always a best first step whenever you see an $x^2 + y^2$ or something like, because that always describes a circle ($r^2 = x^2 + y^2$). And in cylindrical (or polar in some texts) coordinates r = some constant -- as here, where the maximum is 8 and the minimum is 0.

So since $z=x^2 + y^2$ what you do is take $x=r cos(\theta)$ and you get $x^2=r^2 cos^2(\theta)$ and $y^2=r^2 sin^2(\theta)$. Or more precisely: $r^2 \le z \le 8$ which gets you the limits of the inner integral.

To get the middle one you look at a y-z graph and you can see that y starts at zero and ends at $2\sqrt 2$ and x is 0 to pi over 2 because it has to be greater than zero.

The integral ends up being over just $r^2dzdrd\theta$ (since $sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta$ =1)